# Confusion as to how "object" is used in C#

Tags: c#, object

So there is an Object Class, an object type, and an object is an instance of a class. What is the difference between the three?

For example(simplified):

```
Class Human {              //A class named 'Human'
//some code
}

Human boy = new Human();   // 'boy' is an object, or instance of the Human class.
```

Where does the Object Class and object type fall into place here? The term "object" seems to be ambiguous in that it holds 3 meanings/uses.

Comment: Let's be precise here. `boy` is **not an object**. `boy` is a *variable*. A variable *refers to a storage location*. That storage location may hold a *reference*. The reference may be a *null reference* that refers to no object, or it may be a *valid reference* that refers to a specific object.  That specific object is an *instance* of `object`, and in this case, also an instance of `Human`.

Comment: @EricLippert, so are you saying that `new Human()` is the actual object in his example and that `boy` is just referring to that?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: No. The result of the expression `new Human()` is a *reference to an instance of Human*. That reference is a *value* which may be assigned to a *variable*. A variable refers to a *storage location*. The storage location stores a *value*; in this case the *value* is a *reference to a Human*.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Let's suppose that every human has a unique identifier, say their social security number for the sake of argument. A *reference* is like a piece of paper with the social security number written on it. A *variable* is a drawer which you can put that piece of paper in. That drawer in this case has "boy" written on it. When you say `new Human()` somehow a new human gets created and the result of the expression is a piece of paper with their SSN written on it.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: So is `boy` a human? No. It's a drawer. Is it a reference to a human? No. **It's a drawer**. Is the social security number a human? No. **It's a number.** Is the piece of paper a human? **NO. It's a piece of paper.**  The drawer, the paper, the number, none of those are the human. The variable, the storage location, the reference, none of those are the object. *They work together to enable you to refer to the object*, but they are not the object, any more than you are your social security number.

Comment: @EricLippert, so would it be correct to say that you can never truly have an object in your code?  Only a way to refer to an object?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Close. *You never directly manipulate an object of reference type in C#*. You only ever manipulate the object via a *reference*. Objects of value type, by contrast, you do get to manipulate directly. When you have a variable of type `int`, the storage location actually stores an `int`. The object is right there; you do not need to access it indirectly, via a reference.

Comment: @EricLippert, very interesting thanks for the info.  Just out of curiosity, when you are communicating day to day at work, would you refer to `boy` as an object or correct someone if they did?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: In casual conversation of course one easily conflates variables, storage, references and the thing referred to; one assumes that one's fellow compiler developers understand the differences. But in this question we have someone who is clearly confused about the meaning of certain jargon -- and rightly so; it is confusing. I find it best in such cases to not get off wrong-footed; let's be precise about the meaning of "object" and "variable" and whatnot, if that's the subject under discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Object` is a class for which `object` is an alias. Both are types (each class is a type, but not each type is a class).

The term “object” also generally referes to an instance of a type. Thus there are only two distinct (albeit related meanings: a type name for a specific name in the .NET type system, and a general term to denote instances of types in that type system).

Now it gets confusing:

```
object o;
```

Here `o` is an *object* of type `object`. Holy cow!

Comment: My confusion boils down to the object type and types in general:

> Classes are custom types
> Objects are instances of classes 
> An object's type is its class name
> What then, is of type object? 

My head is spinning in circles trying  to understand it.

Comment: @user2154633: What is of type `object`? **All objects are of type `object`.** Just like all books are of type `book` and all oranges are of type `orange` and all tax regulations are of type `tax regulation`.

Comment: @EricLippert: So if orange was an instance of a Fruit class, would it be of type fruit or of type object? Class is a type and object is a type. Would orange be of both types?

Comment: @user2154633 It would be of both types. Types form a *hierarchy* through inheritance (and other stuff) so that a given object can have several types at once, that are related through this hierarchy. Just as you and I are humans, but we’re also mammals and vertebrates and chordates and animals and living things.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: So class types inherit from object types? I always think of inheritance in terms of classes only. For example, I know that all classes inherit from the Object class. I'm not sure why, but I'm having trouble adding types into the mix...

Comment: @user2154633: If I handed you a salmon and you asked me "is this a `salmon` or is it a `fish`?" I'd tell you it was both a `salmon` and a `fish`.

Comment: @user2154633: It is not clear to me what you mean by distinguishing between "class types" and "object types", so let's ignore that question and instead make some correct statements. **All class types except `object` inherit from exactly one class type; `object` inherits from no type.** The inheritance relationship on classes forms a tree with `object` at the root. All enum types inherit from the same class type, `System.Enum`. All non-enum value types inherit from the same class type, `System.ValueType`. Interface "inheritance" is a bit more complicated, so let's not get into it now.

Comment: @user2154633: I think your confusion may be one of terminology. Types can be divided into three broad groups: *reference*, *value* and *pointer* types. Let's ignore pointer types. You can divide the group of reference types into *class*, *delegate* and *interface* types. `object` is a class type.

Comment: @EricLippert: So classes are custom data-types that combine the other types such as object types, string types, int types?

Comment: @user2154633: That's more or less correct. Things get a bit hairy when we consider generic classes, so let's not go there for now. For the purposes of this discussion, when you declare a class, that declares a type.

Comment: @user2154633: You might be interested to read my series from last summer discussing what precisely we mean by "type" in the context of *writing a compiler*. Part one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/08/29/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-quot-type-quot-part-one.aspx, part two: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/07/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-quot-type-quot-part-two.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert: So the System.Object class declares a type, and that type is object, correct? All other classes/custom types inherit from the type declared from System.Object? I apologize if I'm repeating things you've already stated. I'm just trying to understand it in my own words.

Comment: @user2154633: Repeating back what someone just said in your own words is an excellent technique; no worries. Your statements are correct, modulo a few picky technical points. Pointer types are *very special types*; they do not inherit from object. The question of whether *interface* types inherit from object is a philosophical question rather like "if a tree falls in the forest..." -- every *concrete* type that *implements* an interface will definitely inherit from object, so can we say that all interfaces inherit from object? I prefer to say *no*, but the argument is somewhat subtle.

Comment: @user2154633: (And I just realized I left off array types in my list of reference types. And of course that series was two summers ago. How time flies.)

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification and links. Must appreciated. I think things are starting to make more sense.

Answer (score 13):

First off, `object` and `System.Object` are synonyms. It's just two ways to write the same type name. There are not two concepts here.

As for your question of whether it is inconsistent to say both that `object` is a type and that an object is an instance of a type:

Suppose I told you that `fish` is a kind of animal. And then suppose I handed you a (live) salmon and said "that's a fish". Would you then say that I was using "fish" in two inconsistent ways? First I said that `fish` is *part of a classification scheme* and then I said that no, a "fish" was an *actual living animal*. Would you find that confusing? Is it ambiguous? Should we have two words, one for the *classification scheme* and one for *specific instances*?

I think you probably have no difficulty dealing with the ambiguity. You figure out whether a specific fish or the general category of `fish` is being referred to, based on the context of the sentence. And in fact it probably seems quite natural to have the name of a category and the name of an instance of that category be the same thing. It would seem odd if we had one word for the general category of `newspapers` and another word entirely for a specific newspaper, and so on.

Objects, same thing. Just as "fish" is used to mean both *a category* and *a member of the category*, so is "object".

If it helps, when you're referring to objects as instances, say "object" and when you're referring to the type, say `object`. That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is `System.Object` which is the base-class for all classes in .NET.
Secondly, an object is the instance of a class, which means that you have a class, describing how the instances behave (their methods) and their data (giving them an identity and to distinguish them from other instances).

Answer (score 0):

```
// 'boy' is an object, or instance of the Human class.
```

Both! According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx).

> This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

So all instances of all types are objects in .NET.

Also, `object` is just an alias `System.Object`. The two are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

"Object" is C# class that supports all other classes.  It gives you access to a set of methods such as GetType, Equals, and ToString.

Basically your human object inherits from the "Object" class and gains access to all the methods that "Object" has.

Using it as type (such as int), allows you to do some nifty ill-advised things.  You can for instance create an array of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[] array = new object[4];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = "1";
        array[2] = new object();
        array[3] = new StreamWriter(@"C:\file.txt");

        foreach (object o in array)
        {
            if (o != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found an object!  It's type is: " + o.GetType());    
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Didn't find an object");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This gives you the output -

[image]

This gives you an array of objects that don't share a type (besides object)!  Definitely not what they teach you in school.  Also, never do it.

Answer (score 0):

- A `class` *defines* instances, and are usually referred to (with `structs`) as `Types`. These act as templates of behavior for those instances. A `Type` can "inherit" behavior from another `Type`, which is the principle of inheritance. For example (bad example, perhaps), a `Boy` is a *sub-type* of `Human`.
- Instance behavior is defined by the `Type` they are, and are (usually) created by using the `new` operator
- All instances of any `Type` are also instances of `System.Object`, which has a shorthand representation `object`

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Object class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) in .net which is a class that happens to have the name Object.  This is the base class from which all classes derive.  This means that any new class defined has access to all members of the Object class (including the Human class in your example).

You are correct in saying that an object is an instance of a class.  It might sound strange but there can be an `Object` class object.  Exmample:

```
Object o = new Object();
       ^object
^class/type
```

It's a little confusing with the naming, but hopefully that makes sense.

I have always considered type to be a term that can describe a class or a primitive.  So `int` or `Object` could be types, but not `o` from my example.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a code block that defines an object:

```
class MyObject
{
    //Code that defines what the object is and how it behaves
}
```

An "instance of an object" is what you get when you attempt to use the object that was defined in a class:

```
MyObject foo = new MyObject();
```

A "type" is a description of which kind of object you are using. The name of which is at the beginning of the "class" block above.

```
Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType().Name);
```

The line above will print "MyObject".

TL;DR: "class", "Object", "Type" are all so close in meaning, that they are often interchanged when describing code. Each of them relate directly to the definition of an object in object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

Object Class: Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

Object type: The object type is an alias for Object in the .NET Framework. In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object. You can assign values of any type to variables of type object.

Objects: An object consists of instance members whose value makes it unique in a similar set of objects.
All the objects used in C# code are of object type.
When an object is instantiated, it is allocated with a block of memory and configured as per the blueprint provided by the class underlying the object.

Mostly from msdn. You should check it out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to think of each class-type storage location (a variable of type `object` or any other class type would qualify as such) as holding "object IDs", rather than holding objects [the term "reference" has a number of meanings; the term "object ID" would avoid that ambiguity].  Because there isn't really much one can do with an object ID, but there myriad things one may want to do with the object referred to by an ID, in many .net languages, applying the `.` operator to an object ID will access a member of *the object referred to by that ID*.

Note that object IDs have no textual representation, but conceptually it may be useful to assign them arbitrary numbers.  Suppose `Car` is a class type, and `FordFocus` is a class type which derives from it.  A statement

```
Car Fred = new FordFocus();
```

will pick an unused object ID (let's say it picks #42), generate a new instance of the FordFocus class with that ID, and store that ID in `Fred`.  Note that `Fred` cannot and does not hold an instance of `FordFocus`, nor an instance of `Car`.  Instead, all it can hold is an object ID which, if it identifies anything, is guaranteed to identify an instance of either `Car` or a class derived therefrom; in this particular scenario, it holds #42.  If code then says:

```
Object Barney = Fred;
```

the code will check to see whether any object ID that might be stored in Fred could safely be stored in Barney, determine that it can, and proceed to set Barney to #42.

If code then says

```
Fred.Color = Blue;
```

the code won't actually affect `Fred` (which held "#42" before the statement, and will continue to hold "#42" after), but it will affect object #42--turning it into a blue car.

At that point, if code says:

```
Fred = new HyundaiSonata();
```

the system would generate a new ID (e.g. #57), create an instance of HyundaiSonata with that ID, and store #57 into Fred.  That statement would overwrite the value in Fred (it used to hold #42, but now it holds #57) but it would have no effect on Object #42 (which would still be a blue FordFocus).